# Wildcard domain for virtual box in sbs network

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dns

I have a virtual Linux box, running on my Windows 7 computer, which is part of a MS SBS network.  Since a while, I can't change my `hosts` file anymore, perhaps because of some internet security software.  I asked our admin once whether he could establish a wildcard domain entry for my virtual box, e.g. `*.vbox-myname.sbs-ourcompany.local`, which would be very handy (because I develop web sites on it).  He said this would not be possible ...

Every now and then I need a new hostname.  Often the admin is not around at that time.

The hostnames must be available at least to my Windows system, but it wouldn't hurt them to be visible to the internal network as well.
What are my options?

- Is SBS able to provide wildcard domains, or certain versions of it?
- If the reason is a security feature - is it possible to disable it temporarily, to let me configure my hostnames?
- Would it be an option to run a small nameserver on my machine, which would take care of my virtual box, and forward the requests for all other hostnames?
- Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the solution I'd have liked, but at least it works:

I can change the `%SystemRoot%\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` file after booting into protected mode (`F8`).